# How to get the most recent date and time using momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

My response object containing `startTime`, I want to compare all the startTimes and get the latest time to display on timeline.
How can I find the latest Date and time using moment.js
Response I am getting -

```
[{
  name:"abc",
  type:"CALL",
  startTime:"2021-10-13T07:16:55Z",
},{
  name:"def",
  type:"CALL",
  startTime:"2021-10-13T07:18:57Z",
},{
  name:"ghi",
  type:"CALL",
  startTime:"2021-10-15T07:17:05Z",
},{
  name:"jkl",
  type:"CALL",
  startTime:"2021-11-03T12:07:52Z",
}]
```

My code -

```
response.forEach((d)=>{
   if(d.type == 'CALL'){
   console.log("latest start time ",d);
   $scope.view(d); //need to  pass the obj of latest startTime only
   $scope.$apply();
}else{
//Something else
}

})
```

How can I do this using JavaScript or moment?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort array:

```
const dates = [{
  name:"abc",
  type:"CALL",
  startTime:"2021-10-13T07:16:55Z",
},{
  name:"def",
  type:"CALL",
  startTime:"2021-10-13T07:18:57Z",
},{
  name:"ghi",
  type:"CALL",
  startTime:"2021-10-15T07:17:05Z",
},{
  name:"jkl",
  type:"CALL",
  startTime:"2021-11-03T12:07:52Z",
}];

const sortedDates = dates.sort((a, b) => moment(a.startTime).diff(moment(b)))
```

And in `sortedDates` array at position `sortedDates[0]` you have latest  date

Comment: I am having multiple types, I just want to sort for CALL type. By this, the entire response will get sorted right?

Comment: yes, in `const sortedDates` you have descending sorted response

Comment: I don't want to sort the entire response ! I want to sort only those dates which are of type CALL as in the above I have just added CALL types but in real there are many more like MISS_CALL, FAX, etc

Comment: After sort array, you can filter array to get only `type: "Call"`: `sortedDates.filter((a)=> a.type === "CALL")`

Answer (score 0):

Using moment().isBefore property can handle this,

```
const returnLatest =(res)=>{
  let latest = res[0];
  res.forEach(item=>{
    if(moment(item.startTime).isBefore(latest.startTime)){
      latest = item;
    }
  });
  return latest;
}

const data = [{
  name:"abc",
  type:"CALL",
  startTime:"2021-10-13T07:16:55Z",
},{
  name:"def",
  type:"CALL",
  startTime:"2021-10-13T07:18:57Z",
},{
  name:"ghi",
  type:"CALL",
  startTime:"2021-10-15T07:17:05Z",
},{
  name:"jkl",
  type:"CALL",
  startTime:"2021-11-03T12:07:52Z",
}]

console.log(returnLatest(data));
```

It gonna sort it out and return the object with the latest startTime